# Migrated questions linking to the revisions page at the other site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

I migrated this post to ux.stackexchange.com:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57101/are-there-studies-about-the-use-of-categories-and-tags?noredirect=1

The text on this site that says "migrated to ux.stackexchange.com by Stephen Ostermiller" links to the revisions page for the question on user experience rather than the question itself.  In other words, it links to

```
http://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/50254/revisions
```

when I would expect it to link to

```
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50254/are-there-studies-about-the-use-of-categories-and-tags
```

Users then have to click "Return to Question" to see the answers.  That doesn't seem very friendly.

I've also noticed that the post on user experience links back to webmasters revision page as well, rather than to the question here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this was a recent [network-wide change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216280/189912), meant to ensure proper attribution for migrated posts after the source-site copy is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Michael's answer is correct. Due to how the system handles migrated questions (and how diffs are generated), contribution history for migrated questions resides on both sites where contributions happened. Reasons for this are as obvious as users not having accounts on both sites, and as complicated as quirks about how post history is recorded and used.

Clicking on the 'migrated from' link is the easiest way to make sure attribution is given where needed, without scary fundamental changes to table structure and how migrations work.

Ideally, a better fix happens, but that's going to take time. This satisfies the immediate gap.